# Create Dots and connect it with lines

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

i m looking to *create multiple dots in a screen at random coordinates and than connect the dot by its nearest dot*.

or lets say, we have an array of 10 (x,y positions of the view) than ?

> ```
> for (int i=0; i<MATRIX_SIZE; i++) {
>     for (int j=0; j<MATRIX_SIZE; j++) {
>         UIImage *dotImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dot_off.png"];
>         UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:dotImage
>                                                    highlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"]];
>         imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, dotImage.size.width, dotImage.size.height);
>         imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
>         imageView.tag = j*MATRIX_SIZE + i + 1;
>         [self.view addSubview:imageView];
>     }
> }
> ```

Guide me to draw or place same image at random positions.

Thanks

Comment: To me it's unclear what *connect the dot by its nearest dot* means?

Comment: Check the image :   http://depositphotos.com/2991435/stock-illustration-Disco-lights-dots.html   first i need to draw/set images randomly like this and than draw a line between 2 dost.

Comment: You don't want to use `UIView` and images for that. Instead, learn about Core Graphics or SpriteKit on iOS to get some performance.

Answer (score 0):

Randomly generate the `origin` of the image view. Assuming you want the does randomly placed anywhere within `self.view`:

```
// Set the maximum x and y based on the parent view size
CGFloat maximumX = self.view.frame.size.width;
CGFloat maximumY = self.view.frame.size.height;
```

Inside the loop, change the `imageView.frame = ...` to:

```
float randomX = ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) * maximumX;
float randomY = ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) * maximumY;
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(randomX, randomY, dotImage.size.width, dotImage.size.height);
```

If you want the entire image to be within `self.view`, subtract half the width and height from `randomX` and `randomY`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Use time interval to call arc4random() method, to get random values based on random values display the images.

like int randomNumber = (arc4random()%(toNumber-fromNumber))+fromNumber;

call the method with minimum and maximum values for screen.